# Regular Expression in conditional statement using Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am self-studying Python 3 on Sololearn course. And I am now learning regular expression.

Here is the source code:

```
import re

pattern = r"spam"

if re.match(pattern, "spamspamspam"):
    print("Match")
else:
    print("No match")
```

--- according to Sololearn Python 3 Tutorial Course ---

The condition in if statement is quite confusing me. To my knowlegde I have gained, the condition in if statement should be in boolean expression.
However, the re.match function, determines whether it matches the beginning of a string, does not return boolean value (If it matches, the function returns an object representing the match. If not, it returns None).

Therefore, I do not quite understand the if statement of the above code? Can anyone give me some explanations?

Comment: You can see the truth evaluation here, https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 4):

Observe the output of `re.match`:

```
In [2473]: pattern = r"spam"

In [2474]: re.match(pattern, "spamspamspam")
Out[2474]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='spam'>
```

This returns a match object. Now, if we change our pattern a bit...

```
In [2475]: pattern = r"ham"

In [2477]: print(re.match(pattern, "spamspamspam"))
None
```

Basically, the truth value of `None` is `False`, while that of the object is `True`. The `if` condition evaluates the "truthiness" of the result and will execute the if body accordingly.

Your if condition can be rewritten a bit, like this:

```
if re.match(pattern, "spamspamspam") is not None:
    ....
```

This, and `if re.match(pattern, "spamspamspam")` are one and the same.

You should know about how the "truthiness" of objects are evaluated, if you are learning python. All nonempty data structures are evaluated to `True`. All empty data structures are `False`. Objects are `True` and `None` is `False`.

```
In [2482]: if {}:
      ...:     print('foo')
      ...: else:
      ...:     print('bar')
      ...:     
bar

In [2483]: if ['a']:
      ...:     print('foo')
      ...: else:
      ...:     print('bar')
      ...:     
foo
```

Comment: I know comments aren't here for this, but this a really good, well-written and complete answer (+1), congrats on 10k! =)

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Thanks! Appreciate ya.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses 'Truthy' and 'Falsy' values. Therefore, any match would be truthy and a None would be falsy. This concept extends to many places in the language, like checking if there is anything in a list:

```
if []:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Will print false.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) for more information.